# The limit of a sequence of $\sup X_n$ where each $X_n$ is a real subset

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $M \geq 0$ be real positive number and let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:$
$$
\forall x \in X_n : 0 \leq x \leq M
$$
$$
X_{n+1} \subseteq X_n
$$
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty
X_n
=
\{0\}
$$
I would like to know if is it true that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
(\sup X_n)
=
0
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily true. Consider for example
$$
X_n = \{0 \} \cup \{1 - \frac{1}{k} \mid k \in \mathbb N \text{ has a least } n \text{ prime factors} \}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand your answer, why $X_{n+1} \subseteq X_n$

Comment: @MateyMath If $k$ has at least $n+1$ many  prime factors, it has at least $n$ many prime factors. So $1 - \frac{1}{k} \in X_{n+1} \implies 1 - \frac{1}{k} \in X_n$.

Comment: ok @StefanMesken thanks for your answer

Comment: @MateyMath You're welcome. Note that you could also use $X_n = \{0\} \cup \{ 1 - \frac{1}{k} \mid k \geq n \}$ -- my example was needlessly complicated.

Comment: ok @StefanMesken thanks so much now it's more clear for me